# Android Studio layout bonds

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I made a layout for my activity with few buttons and textviews.
But there is a problem.
If i try to move any button or text, the whole thing gets messed up, i mean everything else moves like they are all connected by some bonds.
How do i break those bonds and make them all independent?
I tryed editing xml but it didn't help, they are still following each other.
this is one button for example :

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Calculate"
    android:id="@+id/buttonFcalculate"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textFacc"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textFacc"
    android:layout_marginBottom="87dp" />
```

i removed android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textFacc but it's still the same
Please help.
I can post pictures or codes if needed.
Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="cannon.gaming.physicsdroid.ForceActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Force"
    android:id="@+id/textForce"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textFacc"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="64dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttonFcalculate"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="31dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Mass (in kilograms):"
    android:id="@+id/textFmass"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="42dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Acceleration (in m/s^2):"
    android:id="@+id/textFacc"
    android:layout_above="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Calculate"
    android:id="@+id/buttonFcalculate"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textFacc"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textFacc"
    android:layout_marginBottom="87dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="="
    android:id="@+id/textFequal"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/buttonFcalculate"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/buttonFcalculate"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonFcalculate"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/buttonFcalculate"
    android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="22dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="0"
    android:id="@+id/textFresult"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textFequal"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textFequal"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/editText2" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textForce"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="29dp" />
```

Comment: Post the entire layout, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about what is the problem but I think that everything was connected because of the ***android:layout-align*** you used.

I recommend you to use a `LinearLayout` with `orientation:vertical`.

I made this xml, check if it suits you:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="cannon.gaming.physicsdroid.ForceActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Force"
    android:id="@+id/textForce" />
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner3"
    android:layout_marginTop="29dp" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Mass (in kilograms):"
    android:id="@+id/textFmass"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp" />
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_marginBottom="64dp" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Acceleration (in m/s²):"
    android:id="@+id/textFacc"/>
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttonFcalculate"
    android:layout_marginBottom="31dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Calculate"
        android:id="@+id/buttonFcalculate"
        android:layout_marginBottom="87dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="="
        android:id="@+id/textFequal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="22dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="0"
        android:id="@+id/textFresult"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```